# balanced parenthesis using stack one condition not working

Tags: c++, stack

When I enter `(((` or `{{{[` or `([{` then it is showing success. On all other cases, like `(){}` or `{}[()]`, it is fine. What changes do I need to make here?

I also used an `if` condition to check if the stack is empty then ok, else show the position where the problem arose, but it also did not work.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int ans = -1;
    string text;
    getline(cin, text);
    stack<char> data;

    for(int position = 0; position < (int)text.length(); ++position){
        char next = text[position];
        if (next == '(' || next == '[' || next == '{'){
            data.push(next);
        }
        if (next == ')' || next == ']' || next == '}'){
            if (!(data.empty())){
                char val = data.top();
                data.pop();
                if ((val == '(' && next == ')') || (val == '[' && next == ']') || (val == '{' && next == '}')){
                    continue;
                }
                else{
                    ans = position + 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else{
                ans = position + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        /*
        if (!(data.empty())){
            ans = position + 1;
            break;
        }
        */
    }
    if (ans == -1){
        cout << "Success" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << ans << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This might be a good time to learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: `ans` only gets modified when `next==')' || next==']' || next=='}'` If you have no closing elements, it stays at `-1` which is considered success.

Comment: I'm not sure this approach will work. The usual trick is either recursion, or a state machine, if not both.

Comment: Tip: To make your code easier to follow consider `switch` on the characters.

Comment: @tadman A simple stack is enough. Just need to check at the end if the stack is empty.

Comment: @rustyx Maybe, but this code checks for all brackets all the time when it should be checking for specific ones.

Answer (score 0):

Checking if the stack is empty at the end is the right way to go. A non-empty stack means that there are opened braces still not closed.

Just before `if (ans == -1) {` add something like

```
    if (!data.empty() && ans < 0) {
        ans = text.length();
    }
```

Comment: By entering input as [ ](( ) it is showing output as 5 but the output must be 3 I had used pop() function then why the top char is not removed also it is counting the last char that I didn't pushed in it?

Comment: If you want to print the position of the opening brace that caused the error, then you should remember in the stack the character along with its position: `stack<pair<char,int>> data;`. Then print the position of the first element that is missing the closing brace.